# Div внизу страницы со скроллингом

Tags: html, css

Всем привет!

К примеру, имеется страница высотой 2000px. При размере окна браузера 900px, т.е. появляется скролл по оси y, создается div объект с `position:absolute;`. Как разместить его в самом низу страницы? (bottom:0; размещает объект внизу размера окна браузера, а не истинного размера страницы). Есть идея, используя js, рассчитать высоту всей страницы и указать для блока `top: (высота документа)` - (высота объекта), однако мне кажется все можно сделать не используя js на css, подскажите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для объекта высотой 2000 задайте `position: relative;` тогда координаты дочерних объектов будут рассчитаны относительно него

```css
.page{
   height:2000px;
   position: relative;
}
.absolute{
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
}
```

```html
<div class=page>
<div class=absolute></div>
</div>
```